# How can I setup a nerd font in init.lua?

Tags: neovim, lua

I am in Windows 11. I have downloaded and installed all the fonts 'CascadiaCode'. I have tried to add some thing like `vim.g.guifont="CascadiaCode"` to my init.lua but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do:

```
vim.opt.guifont='CascadiaCode'
```

But If you want the Nerd version of it you have to install it and do:

```
vim.opt.guifont='CaskaydiaCove NFM'
```

Remark: Because 'Cascadia` is a Microsoft reserved name the NerdFont had to adapt the name.

To determine the font that Neovim accept you can use the Vim command: `:set guifont=*`. It will prompt you dialog:

[image]

You can select the font you want.

Then you can use the following command to know what is the associated font string to use for you setting:

```
:set guifont?
```

[image]

Comment: Did you managed to have the font installed and used in Neovim?